# postgresql regexp_replace with dots

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to replace strings between `@` and `.` in email address when selecting from PostgreSQL.

so far I can replace @ and everything after it

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(contactemail, '@(.*)(\.)?', '@xxx') from customer;
```

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('my.email@gmail.co.uk', '@[^\.]+\.', '@xxx.')` -> `my.email@xxx.co.uk`

Comment: Your second version works well, it replaces everything between @ and first dot. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@(.*)(\.)?` pattern matches a `@`, then captures into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then tries to match an optional dot, i.e. this `(\.)?` will never match any text but empty. It is no wonder you match all after `@` with the pattern.

You need to use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '@[^.]*\.', '@xxx.')
```

Or, if you want to only remove the part of text between the *closest* `@` and `.`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '@[^@.]*\.', '@xxx.')
```

The pattern matches

- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^.]*` - zero or more occurrences of any char but `.`
- `\.` - a dot.